# $L^2$ norm estimated by $H^{-2}$ norm.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

If I have a PDE of the form

$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(-\Delta+q)v_1=-(-\Delta+q)v_0, & \text{in}\quad\Omega \\
v_1=0 & \text{on}\quad\partial\Omega
\end{array} \right.$

then is the following estimate correct:
$||v_1||_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C||-(-\Delta+q)v_0||_{H^{-2}(\Omega)}?$
Here the function $v_1$ solves the above PDE, $C\geq0$ and $v_0$ is an explicit function. This seems that it should work because of the way that PDE regularity usually works. I think that the form of my PDE is not important. I am also interested to find a reference for this, so I would be very thankful if someone could provide me with one :)

Comment: Just to clarify, $H^{-2}(\Omega)$ is the dual of $H^2_0(\Omega)$, right?

Comment: @StarBug Yes, you are right.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am more interested in the reference than in an actual proof of the fact. I need this for my masters thesis.

Comment: I don't think the estimate is true unfortunately. I will try to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The estimate is not correct. The classical elliptic a priori estimates in Sobolov spaces do not extend to Sobolev spaces of negative order.
Roughly speaking, the boundary values have to play a role in the a priori estimate, which in the setting of negative spaces they do not.

A simple counter example: Consider on $\Omega:=B_1$ some smooth function $\phi_\epsilon$ such that $\phi_\epsilon=1$ on $B_{(1-\epsilon)}$ and $\phi=0$ on $\partial B_1$. Then (trivially) 
\begin{align}
\Delta \phi_\epsilon = \Delta \phi_\epsilon\quad \text{in } B_1,\qquad \phi_\epsilon=0 \quad \text{on } \partial B_1,
\end{align}
but 
\begin{align}
&||\Delta \phi_\epsilon||_{H^{-2}} \rightarrow 0\quad\text{as}\quad \epsilon\rightarrow 0\quad\text{and}\\ 
&||\phi_\epsilon||_2\rightarrow |B_1|^{1/2} \quad\text{as}\quad \epsilon\rightarrow 0.
\end{align}